# using successive bash instruction in R

Tags: r, bash, shell

I ran successive bash intructions in R using system library, I wanted to obtain all the files in a folder but every instruction isn't save.

I tried

```
system(command = "cd ..")
system(command = paste("cd", path2))
system(command = "dir")
```

but it returned me

> system(command = "cd ..")
> [1] 127
> system(command = paste("cd", path2))
> [1] 127
> system(command = "dir")
> \the root of the R project\

Comment: Why don't you just use `command = paste0("dir ..\\", path2)`?

Comment: As you noticed, this doesn't work. In fact, due to how the shell works this operation doesn't even make sense. Therefore, you need to describe what you *actually* want to accomplish with these steps, so that we can help you find an alternative.

Comment: I find an other solution thanks, I wanted to have the list of file inside a folder, i used the library here

Comment: @AiméJean I am confused, the 'here' package doesn't do that. If you want to have the list of files from the path you indicated, you would normally use `dir(file.path('..', 'path2'))` inside R.